# form is getting submitted to another action method due to query string appended to URL in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a **CarDetails** View in my website which show the details of a car having specific id. This view can only be rendered by giving specific id in query string. Below is the image of car detail having id (_p = 4002).
This page has a form having action method = "Enquiry" and method = "POST" in it.

[Picture for CarDetalils View page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOsG1.png)

**Action Method of CarDetails View**

`public ActionResult CarDetails(int? _p)`

**Action Method of Enquiry Form**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Enquiry([Bind(Include = "name,email,phone,comments")] Referrer referrer)
```

**Html helper for my form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Enquiry", "CarDealer", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "gray-form", @id = "enquiryForm", @role = "form" }))
```

Now the problem is when i click on submit button on Enquiry form then this form request is submitted to **CarDetails** action method instead of submitting to its own action method i.e "Enquiry".

[Picture of network call on Chrome Developer Tools when i submit form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fTiq.png)

I hope you understand this problem. Why is it showing this behavior ? Thanks in advance.

I'm new to ASP.NET and this is my first question ever asked on this platform. This platform and its active users are amazing. Best Wishes.

Comment: Do you have nested forms in your view (which is invalid)?

Comment: No sir i don't. CarDetails.cshtml is a View Page having form in it. @StephenMuecke

Comment: And what is the html rendered for your `<form>` tag (in particular the `action` attribute

Comment: As per my knowledge this may  happen when you have action  attribute in the submit button also, just check it if so , then remove that action attribute from submit button and try again.

If the above not worked , just check do you have any other form in the same view that may also cause problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer!

I wrote a jquery method for my form

```
$("#enquiryForm").submit(function (e) {

    var formData = $('#enquiryForm').serializeArray();

    $.post(
        "/CarDealer/Enquiry", formData, function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data["IsSucceeded"] == true) {
                // code here
            }
            else{
                // code here
            }
            document.getElementById("enquiryForm").reset();
        }, 'json');
    return false;
});
```

Now this form is calling its own action method when i submit it.